# Expiring link plugin is not displaying shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I got this code that was working fine until WP 3.5.1 upgrade. Now it doesn't display anything, and I can't figure it out.

When I put inn the shortcode in admin panel the resulting post or page doesn't display anything. Not even the raw shortcode?

Basically this code display expiring links for amazon s3 content to prevent leaching.

```
define('FPEAS3', __FILE__);
define('FPEAS3_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));

@define('FPEAS3_AWS_S3_ACCESS_ID', '');
@define('FPEAS3_AWS_S3_SECRET', '');

add_action('init', 'fpeas3_init');

function fpeas3_init() {
  add_shortcode('s3', 'fpeas3_shortcode');
}

function fpeas3_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'expires' => '5',
    'bucket' => '',
    'path' => ''
  ), $atts));

  if (!$content = trim($content)) {
    $content = 'Download';
  }

  $keys = array(
    'access_id' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'aws_s3_access_id', true),
    'secret' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'aws_s3_secret', true)
  );

  if (empty($keys['access_id']) || empty($keys['secret'])) {
    $keys = fpeas3_get_static_keys();
  }

  if (empty($keys['access_id']) || empty($keys['secret'])) {
    $error = "Expiring Amazon S3 Links not setup correctly: missing Access ID or Secret.";
    error_log($error);
    if (current_user_can('admin')) {
      return $error;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  return sprintf('<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" class="s3-temp-link">%s</a>', 
    fpeas3_get_temporary_link($keys['access_id'], $keys['secret'], $bucket, $path, $expires), $content);
}

function fpeas3_get_static_keys() {
  return array(
    'access_id' => FPEAS3_AWS_S3_ACCESS_ID,
    'secret' => FPEAS3_AWS_S3_SECRET
  );
}

/**
 * Calculate the HMAC SHA1 hash of a string.
 * @param string $key The key to hash against
 * @param string $data The data to hash
 * @param int $blocksize Optional blocksize
 * @return string HMAC SHA1
 */
function fpeas3_crypto_hmacSHA1($key, $data, $blocksize = 64) {
  if (strlen($key) > $blocksize) $key = pack('H*', sha1($key));
  $key = str_pad($key, $blocksize, chr(0x00));
  $ipad = str_repeat(chr(0x36), $blocksize);
  $opad = str_repeat(chr(0x5c), $blocksize);
  $hmac = pack( 'H*', sha1(
    ($key ^ $opad) . pack( 'H*', sha1(
      ($key ^ $ipad) . $data
    ))
  ));
  return base64_encode($hmac);
}

/**
 * Create temporary URLs to your protected Amazon S3 files.
 * @param string $accessKey Your Amazon S3 access key
 * @param string $secretKey Your Amazon S3 secret key
 * @param string $bucket The bucket (bucket.s3.amazonaws.com)
 * @param string $path The target file path
 * @param int $expires In minutes
 * @return string Temporary Amazon S3 URL
 * @see http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/S3/20060301/s3-dg-20060301.pdf
 */
function fpeas3_get_temporary_link($accessKey, $secretKey, $bucket, $path, $expires = 5) {
  // Calculate expiry time
  $expires = time() + intval(floatval($expires) * 60);
  // Fix the path; encode and sanitize
  $path = str_replace('%2F', '/', rawurlencode($path = ltrim($path, '/')));
  // Path for signature starts with the bucket
  $signpath = '/'. $bucket .'/'. $path;
  // S3 friendly string to sign
  $signsz = implode("\n", $pieces = array('GET', null, null, $expires, $signpath));
  // Calculate the hash
  $signature = fpeas3_crypto_hmacSHA1($secretKey, $signsz);
  // Glue the URL ...
  $url = sprintf('http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s', $bucket, $path);
  // ... to the query string ...
  $qs = http_build_query($pieces = array(
    'AWSAccessKeyId' => $accessKey,
    'Expires' => $expires,
    'Signature' => $signature,
  ));
  // ... and return the URL!
  $tempUrl = $url.'?'.$qs;
  return $tempUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I looked at this code again with fresh eyes. And I got it to work I think. Still testing some things.

I changed this line of code very slightly:

```
**return** sprintf('<a rel="nofollow" href="%s"
 class="s3-temp-link">%s</a>', 
     fpeas3_get_temporary_link($keys['access_id'], $keys['secret'], $bucket, $path, $expires), $content);
```

Changed to:

```
**echo** sprintf('<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" class="s3-temp-link">%s</a>', 
    fpeas3_get_temporary_link($keys['access_id'], $keys['secret'], $bucket, $path, $expires), $content);
```

I'm not a programmer, but after some digging I found there are various ways to display the output.

Any opinions on if this is good way to code it?